# MySQL query randomly takes "forever"

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, innodb

We have an XMPP application that uses MySQL to store information. We are not experiencing any specific load problem so far, but I am trying to be prepared for the worst (or the best, in terms of users;)).

The host on which this MySQL server is installed is a Slicehost slice with 2GB of RAM.

Yesterday, I activated slow query logging to be sure we actually had nothing slow. Unfortunately, it seems that a lot of slow queries were actually found:

```
Reading mysql slow query log from /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
Count: 109  Time=25.57s (2787s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=1.0 (109), xxxxx[xxxxx]@[172.21.xxx.xxx]
  SELECT * FROM `feeds` WHERE (`id` = 'S') LIMIT N
```

This is really strange for me, since id is actually a primary key...
The Table is InnoDB

I did an EXPLAIN:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `feeds` WHERE (`id` = '2650') LIMIT 1;

 +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
 | id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
 +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | feeds | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |       |
 +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There must be another reason why this happens. And there are actaully a lot of similar slow queries (query that use primary keys) in our log.

I think it would make sense to post the MySQL settings here :

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES;
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                       |
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| auto_increment_increment        | 1                           | 
| auto_increment_offset           | 1                           | 
| automatic_sp_privileges         | ON                          | 
| back_log                        | 50                          | 
| basedir                         | /usr/                       | 
| binlog_cache_size               | 32768                       | 
| bulk_insert_buffer_size         | 8388608                     | 
| character_set_client            | latin1                      | 
| character_set_connection        | latin1                      | 
| character_set_database          | latin1                      | 
| character_set_filesystem        | binary                      | 
| character_set_results           | latin1                      | 
| character_set_server            | latin1                      | 
| character_set_system            | utf8                        | 
| character_sets_dir              | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/  | 
| collation_connection            | latin1_swedish_ci           | 
| collation_database              | latin1_swedish_ci           | 
| collation_server                | latin1_swedish_ci           | 
| completion_type                 | 0                           | 
| concurrent_insert               | 1                           | 
| connect_timeout                 | 10                          | 
| datadir                         | /var/lib/mysql/             | 
| date_format                     | %Y-%m-%d                    | 
| datetime_format                 | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s           | 
| default_week_format             | 0                           | 
| delay_key_write                 | ON                          | 
| delayed_insert_limit            | 100                         | 
| delayed_insert_timeout          | 300                         | 
| delayed_queue_size              | 1000                        | 
| div_precision_increment         | 4                           | 
| keep_files_on_create            | OFF                         | 
| engine_condition_pushdown       | OFF                         | 
| expire_logs_days                | 10                          | 
| flush                           | OFF                         | 
| flush_time                      | 0                           | 
| ft_boolean_syntax               | + -><()~*:""&|              | 
| ft_max_word_len                 | 84                          | 
| ft_min_word_len                 | 4                           | 
| ft_query_expansion_limit        | 20                          | 
| ft_stopword_file                | (built-in)                  | 
| group_concat_max_len            | 1024                        | 
| have_archive                    | YES                         | 
| have_bdb                        | NO                          | 
| have_blackhole_engine           | YES                         | 
| have_compress                   | YES                         | 
| have_crypt                      | YES                         | 
| have_csv                        | YES                         | 
| have_dynamic_loading            | YES                         | 
| have_example_engine             | NO                          | 
| have_federated_engine           | DISABLED                    | 
| have_geometry                   | YES                         | 
| have_innodb                     | YES                         | 
| have_isam                       | NO                          | 
| have_merge_engine               | YES                         | 
| have_ndbcluster                 | DISABLED                    | 
| have_openssl                    | DISABLED                    | 
| have_ssl                        | DISABLED                    | 
| have_query_cache                | YES                         | 
| have_raid                       | NO                          | 
| have_rtree_keys                 | YES                         | 
| have_symlink                    | YES                         | 
| hostname                        | SuperfeedrDatabase          | 
| init_connect                    |                             | 
| init_file                       |                             | 
| init_slave                      |                             | 
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size | 1048576                     | 
| innodb_autoextend_increment     | 8                           | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_awe_mem_mb   | 0                           | 
| innodb_buffer_pool_size         | 1073741824                  | 
| innodb_checksums                | ON                          | 
| innodb_commit_concurrency       | 0                           | 
| innodb_concurrency_tickets      | 500                         | 
| innodb_data_file_path           | ibdata1:10M:autoextend      | 
| innodb_data_home_dir            |                             | 
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index      | ON                          | 
| innodb_doublewrite              | ON                          | 
| innodb_fast_shutdown            | 1                           | 
| innodb_file_io_threads          | 4                           | 
| innodb_file_per_table           | ON                          | 
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  | 2                           | 
| innodb_flush_method             | O_DIRECT                    | 
| innodb_force_recovery           | 0                           | 
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout        | 50                          | 
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF                         | 
| innodb_log_arch_dir             |                             | 
| innodb_log_archive              | OFF                         | 
| innodb_log_buffer_size          | 4194304                     | 
| innodb_log_file_size            | 5242880                     | 
| innodb_log_files_in_group       | 2                           | 
| innodb_log_group_home_dir       | ./                          | 
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      | 90                          | 
| innodb_max_purge_lag            | 0                           | 
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups      | 1                           | 
| innodb_open_files               | 300                         | 
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout      | OFF                         | 
| innodb_support_xa               | ON                          | 
| innodb_sync_spin_loops          | 20                          | 
| innodb_table_locks              | ON                          | 
| innodb_thread_concurrency       | 8                           | 
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay       | 10000                       | 
| interactive_timeout             | 28800                       | 
| join_buffer_size                | 131072                      | 
| key_buffer_size                 | 16777216                    | 
| key_cache_age_threshold         | 300                         | 
| key_cache_block_size            | 1024                        | 
| key_cache_division_limit        | 100                         | 
| language                        | /usr/share/mysql/english/   | 
| large_files_support             | ON                          | 
| large_page_size                 | 0                           | 
| large_pages                     | OFF                         | 
| lc_time_names                   | en_US                       | 
| license                         | GPL                         | 
| local_infile                    | ON                          | 
| locked_in_memory                | OFF                         | 
| log                             | OFF                         | 
| log_bin                         | OFF                         | 
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF                         | 
| log_error                       |                             | 
| log_queries_not_using_indexes   | ON                          | 
| log_slave_updates               | OFF                         | 
| log_slow_queries                | ON                          | 
| log_warnings                    | 1                           | 
| long_query_time                 | 3                           | 
| low_priority_updates            | OFF                         | 
| lower_case_file_system          | OFF                         | 
| lower_case_table_names          | 0                           | 
| max_allowed_packet              | 16777216                    | 
| max_binlog_cache_size           | 18446744073709547520        | 
| max_binlog_size                 | 104857600                   | 
| max_connect_errors              | 10                          | 
| max_connections                 | 2000                        | 
| max_delayed_threads             | 20                          | 
| max_error_count                 | 64                          | 
| max_heap_table_size             | 16777216                    | 
| max_insert_delayed_threads      | 20                          | 
| max_join_size                   | 18446744073709551615        | 
| max_length_for_sort_data        | 1024                        | 
| max_prepared_stmt_count         | 16382                       | 
| max_relay_log_size              | 0                           | 
| max_seeks_for_key               | 18446744073709551615        | 
| max_sort_length                 | 1024                        | 
| max_sp_recursion_depth          | 0                           | 
| max_tmp_tables                  | 32                          | 
| max_user_connections            | 0                           | 
| max_write_lock_count            | 18446744073709551615        | 
| multi_range_count               | 256                         | 
| myisam_data_pointer_size        | 6                           | 
| myisam_max_sort_file_size       | 9223372036853727232         | 
| myisam_recover_options          | BACKUP                      | 
| myisam_repair_threads           | 1                           | 
| myisam_sort_buffer_size         | 8388608                     | 
| myisam_stats_method             | nulls_unequal               | 
| ndb_autoincrement_prefetch_sz   | 1                           | 
| ndb_force_send                  | ON                          | 
| ndb_use_exact_count             | ON                          | 
| ndb_use_transactions            | ON                          | 
| ndb_cache_check_time            | 0                           | 
| ndb_connectstring               |                             | 
| net_buffer_length               | 16384                       | 
| net_read_timeout                | 30                          | 
| net_retry_count                 | 10                          | 
| net_write_timeout               | 60                          | 
| new                             | OFF                         | 
| old_passwords                   | OFF                         | 
| open_files_limit                | 10000                       | 
| optimizer_prune_level           | 1                           | 
| optimizer_search_depth          | 62                          | 
| pid_file                        | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid  | 
| plugin_dir                      |                             | 
| port                            | 3306                        | 
| preload_buffer_size             | 32768                       | 
| profiling                       | OFF                         | 
| profiling_history_size          | 15                          | 
| protocol_version                | 10                          | 
| query_alloc_block_size          | 8192                        | 
| query_cache_limit               | 1048576                     | 
| query_cache_min_res_unit        | 4096                        | 
| query_cache_size                | 16777216                    | 
| query_cache_type                | ON                          | 
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate    | OFF                         | 
| query_prealloc_size             | 8192                        | 
| range_alloc_block_size          | 4096                        | 
| read_buffer_size                | 131072                      | 
| read_only                       | OFF                         | 
| read_rnd_buffer_size            | 262144                      | 
| relay_log                       |                             | 
| relay_log_index                 |                             | 
| relay_log_info_file             | relay-log.info              | 
| relay_log_purge                 | ON                          | 
| relay_log_space_limit           | 0                           | 
| rpl_recovery_rank               | 0                           | 
| secure_auth                     | OFF                         | 
| secure_file_priv                |                             | 
| server_id                       | 0                           | 
| skip_external_locking           | ON                          | 
| skip_networking                 | OFF                         | 
| skip_show_database              | OFF                         | 
| slave_compressed_protocol       | OFF                         | 
| slave_load_tmpdir               | /tmp/                       | 
| slave_net_timeout               | 3600                        | 
| slave_skip_errors               | OFF                         | 
| slave_transaction_retries       | 10                          | 
| slow_launch_time                | 2                           | 
| socket                          | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock | 
| sort_buffer_size                | 2097144                     | 
| sql_big_selects                 | ON                          | 
| sql_mode                        |                             | 
| sql_notes                       | ON                          | 
| sql_warnings                    | OFF                         | 
| ssl_ca                          |                             | 
| ssl_capath                      |                             | 
| ssl_cert                        |                             | 
| ssl_cipher                      |                             | 
| ssl_key                         |                             | 
| storage_engine                  | MyISAM                      | 
| sync_binlog                     | 0                           | 
| sync_frm                        | ON                          | 
| system_time_zone                | UTC                         | 
| table_cache                     | 64                          | 
| table_lock_wait_timeout         | 50                          | 
| table_type                      | MyISAM                      | 
| thread_cache_size               | 8                           | 
| thread_stack                    | 131072                      | 
| time_format                     | %H:%i:%s                    | 
| time_zone                       | SYSTEM                      | 
| timed_mutexes                   | OFF                         | 
| tmp_table_size                  | 33554432                    | 
| tmpdir                          | /tmp                        | 
| transaction_alloc_block_size    | 8192                        | 
| transaction_prealloc_size       | 4096                        | 
| tx_isolation                    | READ-COMMITTED              | 
| updatable_views_with_limit      | YES                         | 
| version                         | 5.0.67-0ubuntu6-log         | 
| version_comment                 | (Ubuntu)                    | 
| version_compile_machine         | x86_64                      | 
| version_compile_os              | debian-linux-gnu            | 
| wait_timeout                    | 28800                       | 
+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
237 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Most of our requests are "basic", however, we *need* a tremendous speed!

Any thoughts on what could actually make MySQL so slow?

[**SUMMARY**] To sum up the various answers :

- Remove "LIMIT", change WHERE id = "X"
  into WHERE id = X
- Make sure I don't have any
  script(backup or else) that runs from
  time to time that would consume a lot
  of resources
- Make sure the "host" is not actually the culprit.

Comment: How many records are in the table? I've had this happen with tables that weren't exceptionaly big and fixed it by adding an index..

Comment: Indeed, the table is rather small now : 20k rows.

Comment: isn't the primary key automatically indexed, by virtue of being a primary key?

Comment: not sure I undertsand that... (hey, you broke the layout ;)). 

I would assume that primary keys *are indices*.

Comment: sorry, fixed the layout now, not sure why it did that...  i was trying to change the code block (indented 4 spaces) to a pre block, so that it wouldn't try to highlight it as if it were code.  my question was to Tim, who said he had fixed similar problems by adding an index, which doesn't seem applicable here because the primary key column should be indexed (as the primary key)

Comment: @Kip: Angle brackets are disallowed inside <pre> blocks, they must be escaped. In any case - this question is currently at revision #6. There is one more edit possible before it is turned into a community wiki, so the last edit should be a good one.

Comment: Okay well I'm done here anyway, this question is beyond my realm of expertise. :)  Not sure I understand why they community-wikify the question after a certain number of edits, seems like that just encourages other people to not polish the questions.  (or allows malicious users to force a question into community wiki if they don't want the author to get the rep...)

Comment: @Kip: I think it should encourage people to be clear from the start. In any case, there will always be the danger of collateral damage to questions with a complex formatting issue, like this one here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the mean & variance of slows, you have a problem with the VM host machine (which is not under your control unfortunately).

For those of you pointing out the memory/disk I/O, those numbers are just too big for that. Disk should return in 100ms, not several seconds.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that a "Slicehost Slice" would give intermittent 25 second lags, rather than blaming MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

If id is a primary key, why are you adding the LIMIT clause?

Have you tried specifying the column names you want instead of using a *?

Also, is your Id column int? By specifying '1' instead of 1, you may not be using the index.

Try

```
SELECT * FROM Feeds WHERE id = 1
```

rather than

```
SELECT * FROM Feeds WHERE id = '1'
```

**Edit for comment**

It's better to specify the column names explicitly, in my opinion, because you may need to add columns to that table in the future that are not needed by your app. At that point, you start pulling more data than is needed.

Comment: Hum... you're right, the LIMIT is useless here... but we need all the fields. Do you think specifying them is better than *?

Comment: the LIMIT is useless in this case, but that shouldn't cause it to take 25 seconds to retrieve 1 row of 10 columns of data, right?

Comment: @Julien, I think you aren't actually using the index

Comment: Ok, I will specify the columns we need for future performance.

Comment: I have tried with and woithout quotes... the problems is that given the fact that it I can't reproduce the problem easily, I don't have any difference between the two... could that really be an issue?

Comment: Doesn't EXPLAIN tell us that it's using the primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is very simple, and given that id is a primary key there's no way it should take that long even on a huge table, under normal circumstances.  Just a guess here, but maybe the server is the problem?  As I understand it (from 30 seconds of looking at their homepage), Slicehost is offering you a virtual machine "slice" of a more powerful server.  Could it be that the other slices on the same server are doing heavy disk reads every now and then, temporarily stealing all your resources?  Or maybe it happens when the administrators create/remove slices from the machine for other users.

Does this happen very frequently?

Comment: Technically, the ressources are "guaranteed" in terms of CPU, I don't know about disk accesses though, but I would expect the same kind of guarantee.

It happened 109 times in roughly 12 hours. So it is a lot of times... but a small percentage, since this kind of queries happend about 1M times in 12 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten to get a lot of experience in this kind of thing over the last year, unfortunately.

I agree with others it could be a CPU/disk latency issue (due to the virtual hosting). Is there some way you can get disk latency numbers from the host? Maybe there are spikes.

I also agree that the query is a little weird, in specifying the limit clause and the quoting the index. The SELECT * bit I can totally understand.

I'd guess InnoDB doesn't have enough memory, but with so few rows and giving InnoDB 1 gig, that's not it.

I'd guess the query is wrong. I've seen MySQL do this kind of thing before. Some query takes too long or causes others to start to stack up. But the queries that you see taking too long are simple smaller things that should never take very long.

I have a few suggestions for you:

- Is there some sort of automated backup running that could be locking the table?
- Does this happen on any kind of regular or predictable interval?
- Have you ever been logged in and seen the full process list when this occurs?
- Does it coincide with anything specific (any time people run a certain report, etc)?
- Do you have any very large tables that could be tying up all your memory while they're working on queries, preventing this table from coming in (unlikely)?
- Has this always been the case? Did it start recently? Has the MySQL version changed? Are you able to try another build of MySQL (newer point release, Percona Performance build, etc)?

Some times looking at the full process list while this is going on can be the most helpful.

When we were running into this kind of thing last year, it was watching the process list that finally caught the real issue.

Comment: PS: I hope you will finally end your answer? :)

Comment: Thanks for the many questions.

I don't know about "disk latency numbers". How can I get them?

- There is a backup, but at the "disk" level : snapshots. 
- Interval : I don't know. Is there a good way to find out?
- I was never able to 'see' the spike.
- we don't have any very large table (500k rows at most)
- We actually just got into prod... so, technically it just started but it as always happend!

Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'd ask your host, they should be able to tell you. If you explain the problem and tell them what's happening, they should know what to look for. That said, I expect it's other queries. You'd have to have HORRIBLE disk latency for that to be the problem.

Comment: Hum... ok, then I need to find what queries! Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem before.

Your index is on an **integer** field, and your where clause key is a **string**.  Your index is being defeated by the fact that you are causing a type conversion.  Unquote your key in the where clause.

I was very surprised that mysql behaves this way, it's quite disappointing that it can't detect when this is happening.

Comment: But then, why does it happen only for a small subset of queries?

Answer (score 0):

If the table is larger than what can be kept in memory caches, then it could be that some of these queries needed to touch the disc at some unfortunate moments where something else were putting a lot of load on them?

MySQL tuning is sometimes a bit of a black art. High key-buffer cache contention can also give noticeable slow downs.

You could also try searching the [mysql performance blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) for clues and plausible theories.

Comment: "High key-buffer cache contention can also give noticeable slow downs." ... really? I though that the purpose of a cache was actually to prevent slow-downs?

I'll post the MySQL variables so that you can tell me what you think.

Comment: @Julien, cache contention happens when one query runs and some data is cached, flushing out all previous data, this one will become fast and others slow.  If you run the same kind of query repeatedly, it averages out to a good thing, but if you alternate two kinds of query you lose the benefit that a cache could give and force every read to disk.  They have cache contention because they are contending for cache.

Comment: Can I actually increase the cache to prevent that?

Comment: There are mutexes on the key-buffer cache. I have heard of cases where disabling the key-buffer cache (and thus its mutex) allowed more concurrency thereby improving performance. However, measure-twice-cut-once or you'll end up with worsened performance.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a delayed name resolution, depending on your setup. You could test the speed of DNS lookups from the server with:

```
nslookup www.domain.com
```

If you are getting a slow response, try setting the following in your `/etc/my.cnf` file:

```
skip-name-resolve
# and/or:
skip-networking
```

Also it's a good idea to bind the IP address and port number to remove doubt about the connection path:

```
bind-address=127.0.0.1
port=3306
```

Otherwise I would look at the table locking and troubleshoot from there.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using MyISAM, you might be hitting concurrency problems.